# while loop executing infinitely without any recursive call even after execution flow reaches end of function containing while

Tags: c++, recursion, while-loop, stack, binary-search-tree

below is a function i am using for `inorder` traversal of a `binary search tree` . Everything works well till the loop `while(!st.empty())` gets terminated but after that the execution flow again goes to `while(!st.empty())` hence loop turns into an infinite loop

**structure of node**

```
class bst{ 
private:
    bst *lLink;
    int info;
    bst *rLink;

friend void inorder(bst &);
 };
void inorder(bst &);
```

**calling part**

```
string c;
cout<<"\na, b or c ?";
cin>>c;

 if(c == "a")
 {
  inorder(nodeVec[0]);  //nodeVec is vector containing all nodes (objects) of tree with first element as root
 }

 //......
```

**function**

```
void inorder(bst &item)
{
stack<bst> st;
st.push(item);


while((st.top()).getLeftChild()!=NULL)
{
    st.push(*((st.top()).getLeftChild()));
}

while(!st.empty())
{
    if(st.top().getInfo()==item.getInfo()) //true if traversal is done with all
                                           //left subtree of root and only oneitem remained in stack i.e. only root remained
    {                                     
        cout<<st.top().getInfo()<<endl;

        if(st.top().getRightChild()!=NULL)
            inorder(*(item.getRightChild()));

        else
            st.pop();
    }

    else{
    cout<<st.top().getInfo()<<endl;
    if(st.top().getRightChild()!=NULL)
    {
        bst curr=*(st.top().getRightChild());
        st.pop();
        st.push(curr);
    }
    else{
        st.pop();
    }
    }
}
 cout<<st.empty();  //for testing, this prints 1
} //execution goes here and then again at while(!st.empty())
```

suppose the tree is like this:

```
      69
     /  \
    43  89
   /   /
  24  73
 /
14
 \
  21
```

it gives output

```
14
21
24
43
69
73
89
69   //loop starts again
73
89
69
73
89
...
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, don't use friends. But are you sure that inorder() is never called again? Could you show where you are calling it?

Comment: @arjenz i have updated the question and included the calling part

Comment: Thank you. I am looking it through, but I can't really figure it out yet. I was never using a stack to print a tree inorder, I will try to figure this out first. If I cannot figure it out, I will try to find another way to explain it to you.

Comment: I guess you are never popping a node which has 2 childs, in this case this is the root which makes it confusing. Try adding a pop before going inorder at the right branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be removing the element from the stack when it's printed out.

You're leaving it on the stack in the first block of the if() that checks that the left side of the tree has been completed.

```
if(st.top().getRightChild()!=NULL)
    inorder(*(item.getRightChild()));

// else  // <--- don't use else here.. Always pop
    st.pop();
```

Comment: That was what I thought (see comments). Did it work?

Comment: Yes, it works.  The bug was for nodes with right children as well as nodes with 2 children.  The parent was just not removed from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

This seems way more complicated than it needs to be, Here is a untested version of what I think would work better.

```
struct bst{ 
    int info;
    bst *right;
    bst *left;
};

void inorder(bst & item) {
    std::stack<bst*> st;
    bst* current = &item;
    while(current || !st.empty()) {
        if(current) {
            st.push(current);
            current = current->left;
        } else {
            current = st.top();
            st.pop();
            std::cout << current->info << std::endl;
            current = current->right;
        }
    }
}
```